# binding two values windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need to something like

```
 <TextBlock
 Grid.Column="2"
 Text="{Binding FirstName,LastName}"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

The Windows Phone sdk(silverlight) doesn't support MultiBinding :(
I don't want to use a class that implements joins of two values, I need something faster, because I have a ListBox with about 10 000 values FirstName and LastName

Comment: Why don't you have a FullName property in your view model itself

Comment: Because DB has a key-value structure, I can't spli it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `FullName` property to your ViewModel or whatever object you are using as a DataContext. The value is not stored anywhere you just calculate it at run-time from the values of  `FirstName` and `LastName`. The cost of concatenating two strings is negligible compared to the cost of fetching those 10000 records from a web service or from the isolated storage, so you shouldn't be worrying about that. If there are performance issues, you should implement some form of virtualization instead.

Comment: Thanks.`public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }`